# How to loop through the parameter obtained via web service in php

Tags: php, android, laravel, codeigniter, web-services

i sent a hash map array from android. in the server side i m using php to parse the param and save into database. but no idea how to loop through it

i used foreach loop and tried to print key, value pair. but its not working

parameter fetched from web service

```
{1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=2, 6=2, 7=2, 8=1, 9=2, 10=2, 11=2, 12=2, 13=1, 14=2, 15=0}
```

where the first part is question number and second part is the corresponding answer. How to loop through it and save into data base. pleaes suggest an idea

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? You haven't added any of that code in question, neither the code sending that data, nor the code parsing it

Comment: By keeping this structure, you need to write your own "parser" for it, for example using `explode()` several times to destructure your response into key-value pairs. If you are able to send a valid JSON from your Android app, that will be much easier to understand by your PHP backend and you don't need that much self-written code.

Comment: @Johannes Thanks. Removed the curly braces and using explod, it workded

Answer (score 1):

In the data, the '=' needs to change to '=>' to be a valid PHP key/value pair.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Just an added info to make things work in proper way.
if we are communicating through webservices/api then using data format as json/xml will make it simler to parse it. 
Like in this two different languages(android and php) are communicating. They both have there different way to handle array etc.
due to this most REST API uses json and SOAP uses XML for data transfer.